# How to use Service Accounts send email using Gmail API and Node.js

Tags: node.js, gmail-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm building an send email function using the Gmail API.

I'm trying to send mail using Service Accounts send email.

I'm using jwt  instead of OAuth2 authenicate.

Error sending email: Precondition check failed.

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const {JWT} = require('google-auth-library'); 
const CLIENT_EMAIL =  
const PRIVATE_KEY =  
const authClient = new JWT({
  email: CLIENT_EMAIL,
  key: PRIVATE_KEY,
  scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms.responses.readonly',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send', 'https://mail.google.com/',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose'
  ]
});

 
async function sendEmail(subject, body, to) {
  try {
      // authenticate using credentials file
      await authClient.authorize();
      // create gmail 
    const gmail = google.gmail({ version: "v1", auth: authClient });
    const message = [ 
      'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8', 
      'To: ' + to,
      'Subject: ' + subject ,
      '',
      body,
    ].join('\n');
   
    const encodedMessage = Buffer.from(message).toString('base64').replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_').replace(/=+$/, '');
    const res = await gmail.users.messages.send({
      userId: 'me',
      requestBody: {
        raw: encodedMessage
      }
    });
    console.log('Email sent:', res.data);
     return  res.data
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error sending email:', err.message);
    return  err.message
  }
}
```

```
  const message = [ 
      'Content-Type: text/html; charset=rfc822', 
      'To: ' + to,"\n",
      'From:' + from, "\n",
      'Subject: ' + subject , "\n\n", 
      body,
    ].join('');
```

show Error sending email: Precondition check failed.

Can JWT be used instead of OAuth2?

or add more functions, please recommend me.

thank you.

Comment: And yes, you must have a domain name, organization, and pay to use Google Workspace Admin

Answer (score 1):

precondition check failed

means you are using a service account but have not properly configured domain wide deligation to the google workspace domain and haven't deligated to a user on the domain from your code

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it by adding the domain name. and add permissions to use scopes gmail in Google Workspace Admin ,

Comment: Make sure to accept the anwser if it helped you